# Matching algorithm in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have more than 3 million rows in my table. When the user try to insert or update this table I have to check the following conditions sequentially.(Business Need)

1. Does any of the row has same address?
2. Does any of the row has same postcode?
3. Does any of the row has same DOB?

Obviously the newly inserted or updated row will match lot of the records from this table.

But the business need is, the matching process should end when the first match (row) found and that row has to returned.

I can easily achieve this using simple "SELECT" query . But it's taking very long time to find the match.

Please suggest some efficient way to do this.

Comment: UNIQUE constraints and proper exception handling?

Comment: Have you indexed the table on these fields?

Comment: For a fast select you need to have all of those fields (address, post code, DOB) indexed otherwise you're performing a full table scan for each field.

Comment: How to stop the match process when it found the first match?

Comment: @Gansun: Write a stored procedure which will check and control the flow of the biz logic.

Comment: Already I have written the stored procedure for this biz logic and working well but slow.

Comment: Does select top 1 will stop on the first match or it will match all rows and selects the top 1 from matched?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way to return after the first match, use `LIMIT 1`.

You may want to maintain a table of either birth dates or postcodes and have each row link to a user, so that you can easily filter customers down to a smaller set. It would allow you to perform a much faster search on the database.

Example:

```
dob      | userID
1/1/1980 | 235
1/1/1980 | 482
1/1/1980 | 123
2/1/1980 | 521
```

In that scenario, you only have to read 3 rows from the large users table if your target date is 1/1/1980. It's via a primary key index, too, so it'll be really fast.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have LIMIT clause!

Comment: Really? That sucks. I suppose you could limit something like `WHERE id >= 0 AND id < 10000`, then `WHERE id >= 10000 AND id < 20000`, etc. until you get a row. Anyway, the rest of my suggestion still stands.

Comment: It does indeed suck!  You can emulate the functionality by using the ROW_NUMBER() function.